# variable for SQLLOGDIR not found

Tags: backup

I am using ola hallengren script for maintenance solution. When I run just the Database backup job for user database I get the following error. Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Variable SQLLOGDIR not found).  The step failed.

I have checked the directory permissions and there is no issue there. The script creates the job with no problem. I get error message when I try to run the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my SQL Server 2012 version, the error was during the dB backup using Ola's scripts, as mentioned above the issue is with the output file, I changed the location and the output file from the SQL Job and reran the job successfully (refer the attached screenshot for reference.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue just the other day. I run a number of 2017  servers but the issue happened when I started running on a 2012 server.

I've dropped Ola a mail to confirm but best I can make out is that the SQLLOGDIR parameter specified in the 'advanced' tab for the step (for logging outputs) is not compatible with 2012 and maybe below 2017 though I have not tested these.

HTH,

Adam.

Comment: In answering your question, I realized that was also the answer to mine :) so thank you!

Comment: The SQL Server Agent token SQLLOGDIR only exists in SQL Server 2014 and later.

Try dropping the job, and run MaintenanceSolution.sql again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace this part in the advanced tab with the job name for example :

`$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBNAME))` replace it with `CommandLogCleanup_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))` so then it will look like this:

`$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))\CommandLogCleanup_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(DATE))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(TIME)).txt`

instead of this:

`$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))\$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBNAME))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(DATE))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(TIME)).txt`

Do this for all the other jobs if you don't want to recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the job output file.

When you create a maintenance job using the Ola script it will automatically assign output file to the step. Sometimes the location does not exist on the server.

I faced the same issue, then I ran the integrity script manually on the server and it completed without error, then I found that the error is in job configuration.

I changed the job output file location and now job also running fine.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to build the string for the `@output_file_name` parameter element by element before calling the stored procedure. If you look into Olas code you will see that is exactly what he is doing.

I have tried to describe this in more detail in the post [Add SQL Agent job step with tokens in output file name](https://sqladm.blogspot.com/2023/02/add-sql-agent-job-step-with-tokens-in.html).